# Performance issues in remote PowerShell invocation

Tags: c#, powershell

I have an agent running on a Hyper-V host that is expected to run the custom powershell cmdlets that I ask it to run from a remote system. What I have observed is that the custom powershell cmdlets take very less time when I RDP to the host and execute it on the powershell window. But when it is invoked from the agent, it takes about 10 times more time to execute.

The agent creates a PowerShell object and adds the script to be executed to it using the AddScript method and finally does a BeginInvoke and then loops until the result of the async invocation has Completed (asynccmd.IsCompleted). It takes a lot of time for the command to complete. I am not sure why it is taking time since I have confirmed that running the command manually doesn't take that much time.

1. What are the ways I can debug this?
2. is it a know issue or something like that?
3. Is there a better way to invoke a powershell cmdlet on the Host?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I haven't shared the code since I am not sure what help it would be, since I am getting the results fine. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: Made the question more clear.

So the agent is written in C# and is running as a windows service. And from that windows service the Powershell object is created and the command invoked using the BeginInvoke invocation which run asynchronously and which is the function that is taking time I think. I guess I can use windbg to debug but I am not totally sure.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, although that seems like debugging on the local computer which is not exactly the case for myself.

Comment: you should be able to use the local to reproduce

Comment: @MethodMan Ah I realize I didn't make my question very clear. Have edited it now. The problem is in the C# exe that is invoking the powershell command.

Comment: there are ways to execute powershell from C# along with using the `System.Diagnostics.Process Class` do a google search on `C# Executing Powershell script` I have found several issues trying to do that in the past but if you can get the script to run in a `ps script` then you can just call call the script itself from within C# and it should execute properly.. I do the same thing currently when I want to execute Unix Shell scripts from my C# applications. Took a little bit of messing around but I finally got it to work.

Comment: I didn't understand when you said, "if you can get the script to run in a ps script...". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: ps = `PowerShell` Script